# Squash rows based on single common value

Tags: r

I have data where each row has an ID. For some rows, the IDs match others. This means that they are part of the same "group". They may have values in different columns, but they don't over lap. I'm trying to squash the rows with the same IDs, but can't figure it out, (so in the example below, the result would just have 3 rows, for IDs 1 2 and 3)

Example (run the snippet):

I've tried using `aggregate`, but I can't find a concat function for Strings. Thanks.

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">ID</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Name</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Info</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">A</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">B</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Jack</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">ABC</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">x</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">x</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">2</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Marin</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">ABC</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">2</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Y</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">3</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">3</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">ABC</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">X</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">3</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Giraffe</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Y</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: As PoGibas pointed out, your question is half baked

Comment: Woops, fixed. @Onyambu

Comment: `aggregate(df[,2:4], list(df[,1]), function(x) unique(x))`?

Comment: "arguments must have same length", @flee

Comment: aggregate(.~ID,df,I)

Comment: to concat strings you can use `paste` or `paste0`

Comment: @flee: got yours to work, however, the concatenated values are like `c(item1, NA)` where I assume NA comes from blank values in the rows it appended. Ideas?

Comment: Seem to have fixed by adding an `na.omit()`